# IS MySQL CPU time meant to be so long?

Tags: mysql, centos

We have been running a lot of complex scripts recently on a new server that's required a lot of monitoring of MySQL. The server has only ever been on a maximum of say 20 hours at one time. But regardless Mysql's cpu usage time just keeps on going and going.

I'm guessing that this is meant to happen because its a service that is continually running but just wanted to confirm this.

According to `top` mysql has been running for `380:09.23`.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1697 mysql     20   0 2687376 504752  10036 S  82.3  6.3 380:09.23 mysqld
```

Comment: Well perhaps the bigger question here is to your knowledge are there services which are using MySQL during this time, and is the usage level roughly what you would expect?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wouldn't expect a single script or query to be ran for that length of time no.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a multithreaded service. If it’s processing several queries at a time, consuming more than one CPU core (which is shown as more than 100% in CPU column of top), then more than one second is added in TIME+ column for this one second of physical time.

You may monitor which threads are currently running within compound MySQL process by issuing

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

in mysql console (i.e. where you usually issue SQL statements to this server).

**Addition:**

I have a low throughput MySQL 5.6 instance that hasn't been restarted since Jan. 4, 2018. It's runs on debian, bare-metal ARM, it doesn't usually have many idle connections hanging (I see two right now). It has consumed about 2225 minutes of CPU time since then:

```
$ ps -eo pid,lstart,time,cmd | grep mysql
 3895 Thu Jan  4 23:09:11 2018 1-13:04:45 /usr/sbin/mysqld ...
```

I also just took two polls and it added 15 seconds of CPU time in 140 minutes of physical time:

```
$ date; ps aux | grep mysql
Tue Oct  1 16:37:16 UTC 2019
mysql     3895  0.2 10.7 439512 223352 ?       Sl    2018 2224:37 /usr/sbin/mysqld

$ date; ps aux | grep mysql
Tue Oct  1 18:57:50 UTC 2019
mysql     3895  0.2 10.7 439512 223352 ?       Sl    2018 2224:55 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Therefore, at least for that instance it's not normal to add TIME+ metric without actual work performed.

I suspect it's maybe possible that TIME+ would increase without correspondent %CPU in virtual environments, but then you would still need to monitor PROCESSLIST and maybe SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to catch what is consuming CPU cycles in this case.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: The `top` output sample shows it consumed 82% at the time of polling. So it was doing something contributing to TIME+ increase. If there were no scripts running at  the time then you may try to use `show processlist` to diagnose what it is doing (like a backup procedure or there maybe other similar background processes).

Comment: Yes but beforehand it has not been doing anything I just showed this example so that you could see the total time. Well aware of proceslist and its function. But for the msot part it will show nothing happening. MYSQLD jsut continualy stacks up time wethere or not its taking up cpu process or not. So my question is why. Is it meant to.

Comment: Please post TEXT of your FIRST PAGE of top output and complete TEXT of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; for analysis.